# Sort a List of String array objects

Tags: java, list, sorting, comparator

How can i Sort a list of String array objects alphabetically.

I Set my List as follows:

```
List CurrentRankingsList = rankings.getRankings();
```

I have a List of String objects like this:

```
[["Dwayne","5"], ["Bill","4"], ["James","3"], ["Sally","3"]]
```

How can i sort this list by the Names, alphabetically whilst maintaining the List structure eg `[["Bill","4"], ["Dwayne","5"], ["James","3"], ["Sally","3"]]`
I've tried the following but list is not getting sorted correctly

```
      (Updated code from original question )    
           Collections.sort(CurrentRankingsList, new Comparator<Rankable>() 
            {
            @Override
            public int compare(Rankable o1, Rankable o2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String testo1=o1.getObject().toString();
            String testo2=o2.getObject().toString();
            int x = o1.getObject().toString().compareTo(o2.getObject().toString());
            return  o1.getObject().toString().compareTo(o2.getObject().toString());
            }
        }) ;
```

On debugging the compare we get a Paul (o1.GetObject.ToString) vs Nathan(o2.GetObject.ToString)

Comment: Why do you use raw types ?

Comment: [Collections#sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) also: [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907683/sort-a-two-dimensional-array-based-on-one-column
You will get the idea from here

Comment: This looks very similar to JSON if you just adjust the format. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15855548/how-to-sort-array-of-json-objects-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i Sort a list of String array objects alphabetically.

- Declare list or any collection with type: `ArrayList<String[]>`, `List<String[]>` otherwise the Collection will be regarded as raw type and we will face run-time error overhead for type unsafe operation.
- You will need to pass `String[]` as type to `Comparator`

  ```
   Collections.sort(CurrentRankingsList, new Comparator<String[]>() 
   {
      @Override
      public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  return o1[0].compareTo(o2[0]);
       }
   }) ;
  ```

  Assuming that `CurrentRankingsList` is the list of array string.
- For such case,  more cleaner approach would be to declare a class for example, `Player` with two attribute(name, rank) and then sort based upon the instance of that class.

  ```
   class Player
   {
      String name;
      int rank;

       // your other code with constructor and getter, setter method    
    }

   ArrayList<Player>currentRankingsList = new ArrayList<>();

   Collections.sort(CurrentRankingsList, new Comparator<Player>() 
   {
      @Override
      public int compare(Player o1, Player o2) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
       }
   }) ;
  ```

Comment: I think CurrentRankingsList is either a List of List<String> or a List of String[].

Comment: I think you might be right but the OP's mentioning about `How can i sort this list by the Names` is quite confusing :)

Comment: That wouldn't change your code too much ^^ `public int compare(String[] o1, String []o2) {return o1[0].compareTo(o2[0]);}`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. 1st one error'd because we were comparing an object to a string. So we tried second and debugged at the compare and see that Paul vs Nathan returns a 2. The list is then not sorted correctly, i think it does some sorting which appears random.

Comment: @Fearghal, could you please rephrase. Are you saying the proposed approach using `Comparator<String[]>` isn't working ?

Comment: Apologies - i had capitals in the middle of some strings and didnt realize the sort would be affected by them. Fixed. Thanks a million Sage.